# eclipse generates the next errro The type com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList$Builde

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, cucumber, appium

I have a project in java, i imported it in eclipse, but i always get the next error

> Multiple markers at this line
>
> - The type com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList$Builder       cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
> - The type com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap$Builder    cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

[image]

[image]

[image]

My java version is "1.8.0_251" and JRE is 1.7

Comment: Where is that type on your Java Build Path?

Comment: what kind of type do you mean?

Comment: The one referred to in the error message.

Comment: I get the error when i import the next library: import io.appium.java_client.TouchAction;

if i remove it, the project build it, but i need the library, because i use the next  TouchAction t = new TouchAction(driver);